# Symbolic Link local .jpg file to .jpg file on the internet

Tags: linux, symlink, remote

Is there any way to have a symbolic link that links a local .jpg file to a .jpg file on the internet in a l/unix environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not normally possible.

The only possible way I can think of that this could even be attempted would be to use a FIFO or similar and have a process monitoring it to download the file when its accessed.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your best hope would be to use something like [httpfs](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/). But the http site must be specified at mount time.

Maybe similar fuse filesystems exist that won't require a host to be given at mount time, but I don't know any.